# How do I solve a Cannot read property error?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, observable

The following is a code block that's throwing an error in the console. The function is implemented in the service of my angular application.

```
    lastEmployeeID()  //code block that's throwing error
    {
     let temp= this._http.get(this._employeesUrl).subscribe((employees:any) 
      =>  temp = employees,err => console.log(err));
     let last=temp[temp.length-1].id;
     return last;
    }
```

Here is the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at
>   EmployeesService.lastEmployeeID (employees.service.ts:43) at
>   AddEmployeeFormComponent.onSubmit (addemployee-form.component.ts:19)
>   at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AddEmployeeFormComponent.html:3) at
>   handleEvent (core.js:13542) at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15051) at
>   Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14638) at
>   dispatchEvent (core.js:9957) at eval (core.js:12296) at
>   SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4339) at
>   SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain the issues here:

```
lastEmployeeID() {
  // Here you're assigning the subscription to the get request to temp
  let temp= this._http.get(this._employeesUrl).subscribe(
    (employees:any) =>  temp = employees, // This will only happen when the get request completes
    err => console.log(err)
  );

  // By the time you get here, the get request will most likely not 
  // have finished and so "temp = employees" will not have been called. 
  // So you are trying to get temp[temp.length-1] where temp is not an 
  // array but rather a subscription.
  let last=temp[temp.length-1].id;
    return last;
  }
```

Here is one way you could approach this:

```
lastEmployeeID(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this._http.get(this._employeesUrl).subscribe(employees => {
      observer.next(employees[employees.length-1].id)
    }, err => {
      console.log(err))
      observer.error(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Making this change is affecting my other functions which shouldn't happen. I can't seem to figure out the reason.

Comment: Yes the function now returns an observable instead of a value. You need to subscribe to the result of this function from wherever you're calling it.

Comment: Okay thanks that worked.
But now i am doing an http.post which updates a backend server json object.
But only on refreshing the webpage i am able to see the updated list.